# Executing java application through a bat file stops

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I'm executing a java application through a .bat file and it's executing as well. But sometimes the console stops to show the logs (The process is stopped) and pressing enter in the console the process returns its execution. The program doesn't need user interaction and the problem occurs randomly.

I can't put prints here because the network is closed.
I've tried to set thread priorities to MAX_PRIORITY and no success.

The application is running on Windows 10 x64, and JRE 1.8.

The script into .bat is:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar myapplicationname.jar
```

Comment: Is there any error log generated?

Comment: No errors, i execute on eclipse too and this problem doesn't happen

Comment: So, i've ran the application through Eclipse and this problem never happened. The execution don't need users interaction. Every block of code has exception treatment with logs. I think its something with the windows threads